# If $p(x,y)$ is a homogeneous polynomial, and $p(x,\lambda x)$ is identically $0$, then $y-\lambda x$ is a factor of $p(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-curves

Suppose $p(x,y)$ is a homogeneous polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$, say, and 
$p(x,\lambda x) = 0$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$ Then why exactly must $y- \lambda x$ divide $p(x,y)$? Intuitively, I suppose it isn't too difficult to fathom, as plugging $\lambda x$ into $y$ kills the polynomial, but I can't seem to show it algebraically (I think I'm just missing a very simple point..).

Let $p(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^ky^{n-k}.$ Then $$p(x,\lambda x) = \sum_{k=0}^na_k\lambda^{n-k}x^n = 0,$$ so $\sum_{k=0}^na_k\lambda^{n-k} = 0.$ How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You don't need $p$ homogeneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we substitute $z=y-\lambda x$ we'll get another homogeneous polynomial $p(x,y)=q(x,z)=\sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^kz^{n-k}$. We know that $q(x,0)=0$, hence, the coefficient $c_n=0$ and $z$ can be factored out.